# K-medoids: k = total dataset

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining

I have a project about K-medoids, how to perform K-medoids if I set K = total dataset.

ex: Dataset[0,1,2,3]

K = 4

this means, we dont have non-medoids for iteration. so what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Setting k = N means that every point is a cluster.

You don't need to run the algorithm at all then, but you are already done.

In general, if a cluster has only 1 object, you cannot *improve* by swapping.